# After renaming a field in MongoDB collection, my query in c# doesn't work

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection and I put some data in it. After some times I decided to rename one of my fields in MongoDB. After I renamed the field "Name" to "Name1" in my collection in mongoDB, my query stopped working. What is the issue?

```
public class MyClass{
  public int Name {get; set;}
  public int Description {get; set;} 
}
static void Main()
{
 var builder = Builders<MyClass>.Filter;
 var query = builder.Eq( a => a.Name, "John")));
 Console.WriteLine(collection.Find(query).Result);
}
```

Comment: Because your query is looking for name not name1?  I'm not sure what you mean by renamed a field... it's a collection of documents, so did you rename it on just one doc? And how is your collection defined? IE are you returning a collection of bsondocs or a collection of "MyClass"?

Comment: The Name in my query is the property of MyClass but name1 is the name of field in collection. Now I need "MyClass.Name" points to name1 instead of name. And I have a collection of MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is trying to find all documents with the field `Name` == 'John', but the documents in the collection don't have the field `Name`, for that reason your query is not working.

Update: Your query, using a BsonDocument instead your MyClass model

`var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Name1", "John");
collection.Find(filter).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is there any way to tell application that the field is renamed?

Comment: maybe this link can help you http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/bson/mapping/